# Merge sort algorithim not working consistently and giving wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have tried to implement merge sort and this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSort{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter the elements into array");
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        divide(a,0,n-1);
    }

    public static void divide(int a[], int si, int ei){
        if(si>=ei){
            return;
        }
        int mid = si + (ei-si)/2;
        divide(a,si,mid);
        divide(a,mid+1,ei);
        conquer(a,si,mid,ei);
    }
    
    public static void conquer(int a[],int si,int mid, int ei){
        int newa[] = new int[ei+1];
        
        int i=si;
        int j=mid+1;
        int k=0;

        while(i<=mid && j<=ei){
            if(a[i]<=a[j]){
                newa[k]=a[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                newa[k]=a[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while(i<=mid){
            newa[k]=a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<=ei){
            newa[k]=a[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        for(int p=0;p<=ei;p++){
            System.out.println(newa[p]);
        }
        
    }
}
```

For some reason the code works for some inputs but doesnt for others.Example-
it doesnt work here

> Enter the size of array 4 Enter the elements into array 9 5 7 8 5 9 7
> 8 0 0 7 8 9 5

but it works here

> Enter the size of array 4 Enter the elements into array 7 5 6 4 7 5 6
> 0 0 4 5 6 7

I realise that the way i have tried to display the sorted array is not proper and it will print the values even during recusive call. Ignoring this, how do i solve the issue with sorting? I have tried to debug but couldnt find anything wrong with the code

Comment: You don't merge anything, as `conquer` does not retain `newa`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust then how come it is working with one the sample inputs? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct only one thing missing is, you are not storing modified i.e conquered elements back to array ***a***. One more thing, size of intermediate array i.e ***newa*** should be ***ei-si***.

This is modified code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter the elements into array");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        divide(a, 0, n - 1);
    }

    public static void divide(int a[], int si, int ei) {
        if (si >= ei) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = si + (ei - si) / 2;
        divide(a, si, mid);
        divide(a, mid + 1, ei);
        conquer(a, si, mid, ei);
    }

    public static void conquer(int a[],int si,int mid, int ei){
        int newa[] = new int[ei-si+1];
        
        int i=si;
        int j=mid+1;
        int k=0;

        while(i<=mid && j<=ei){
            if(a[i]<=a[j]){
                newa[k]=a[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                newa[k]=a[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while(i<=mid){
            newa[k]=a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<=ei){
            newa[k]=a[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        for(int p=0;p<=(ei-si);p++){
            a[si+p] = newa[p];
            System.out.print(newa[p]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        
    }
}
```